# How to efficiently network an application in Java

Tags: java, networking

I was wondering if someone could give me a clue. The situation is we have one computer that has a server application, the rest have a client application. Now my question is how would i keep track of the server ip address? What I want is have the clients automatically hunt the server application, regardless of the ip address and find it, because using a wireless network computers are using DHCP. So I was wondering is there anything that can be buried in a computer using Java with which other computers can identify the application. Thanks.

Comment: Are the on the same network or do they connect over the internet?

Comment: This is what DNS is for.  Have you got a DNS service?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The "good" way is to use DNS (imho the ONLY solution in a productive environment), as @Peter Lawrey already mentioned, and i would prefer that solution.

You have two other possibilities:

- Let the server broadcast his address on the network.
- Let the clients scan the network.

Both this solutions are not ideal, because you create a lot of noise on the network, may be blocked by a firewall, etc. Therefore, i really suggest you to use DNS.

If you can not use the DNS solution i would go with a solution that lets the clients search for the server.

Take a look at this [SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11547082/fastest-way-to-scan-ports-with-java) question, might get you started.

Answer (score 1):

If they're on the same physical network, your server can broadcast its IP address via UDP to the broadcast address for that sub net.

You could even follow the [uPnP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Universal_Plug_and_Play) standard.

Alternatively, you could host the location of the server from a known other location, like a web server. For example, call an action on the known web server to retrieve the IP address of the server. This allows you to utilize DNS to look up the first host, then go from there.

Answer (score 0):

If you know the DNS-Name of the server you can use that name instead of the IP. Java takes care of the DNS lookup.

Otherwise, I guess the simplest solution is just to scan the IP range of your network and just try to connect to each IP and test if it works.

Other solutions would include broadcasts by the server and would be much more complicated and maybe overkill for a application hosted in a small network.

Comment: i see, actually the application is for a  cyber cafe were when a computer starts it must look for the server computer to be controlled from the server

Comment: Than I would go for the DNS approach. If they are running Windows you can use the PC Name assigned by Windows as the DNS name of the server and you should be fine. Alternatively some (read: better) routers allow to assign static IPs to some of the PCs in the network. So you could assign a static IP just to the server.