# IP Address in a range

Tags: java, arrays, arraylist, ip

Can someone help to solve the problem here. I want to check IP addresses in specific range using command line.

For example I run program in cmd "java IPAddressCheck 1.1.1.1 5" and the output should be:

```
1.1.1.1
1.1.1.2
1.1.1.3
1.1.1.4
1.1.1.5
```

this is my code and the problem is went i run the code it will count start with "1.1.1.2" until "1.1.1.6".

```
import java.util.*;
import java.net.*;


public class IPAddressCheck 
{
public static void main(String[] args) throws Exception
{
        String startIp = args[0];
        int number = 0;

        if (args.length != 1)
        {
            try
            {
                number = Integer.parseInt(args[1]);
            }
            catch(IllegalArgumentException e)
            {
                System.out.println("Error");
                System.exit(0);
            }

            ArrayList<String> ipRange = new ArrayList<>();
            String currentIp = startIp;

            for(int i = 0; i < number; i++) 
            {
                String nextIp = nextIpAddress(currentIp);
                ipRange.add(nextIp);
                currentIp = nextIp;
                //System.out.println("----------------------------------");
                System.out.println(nextIp);
            }   
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println("Wrong number of arguments");
            System.out.println("Please try again");
        }
}


public static final String nextIpAddress(final String input) 
{
        final String[] tokens = input.split("\\.");
        if (tokens.length != 4)
            throw new IllegalArgumentException();
        for (int i = tokens.length - 1; i >= 0; i--) 
        {
            final int item = Integer.parseInt(tokens[i]);
            if (item < 255) 
            {
                tokens[i] = String.valueOf(item + 1);
                for (int j = i + 1; j < 4; j++) 
                {
                    tokens[j] = "0";
                }
                break;
            }
        }
        return new StringBuilder()
                .append(tokens[0]).append('.')
                .append(tokens[1]).append('.')
                .append(tokens[2]).append('.')
                .append(tokens[3])
                .toString();    
}
}
```

Comment: what do you pass in the command line arguement?

Comment: how did you do? have you found a solution?

Answer (score 2):

You have to initialize your range with the first ip address first and then make the number of iterations equals to number of addresses-1, because you have already one address in your list:

```
ipRange.add(currentIp);
for(int i = 0; i < number-1; i++) 
{
    currentIp = nextIpAddress(currentIp);
    ipRange.add(currentIp);
}
```

Glad to see, that you found my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/32943793/4053652) useful))

Answer (score 1):

It's simple. Your statement order changes the IP too early. Edition your `for` loop to look like this:

```
        System.out.println(currentIp);
        ipRange.add(currentIp);
        for(int i = 1; i < number; i++) 
        {
            currentIp = nextIpAddress(currentIp);
            ipRange.add(currentIp);
            System.out.println(currentIp);
        }
```

In the beginning, your `currentIp` is your starting IP, that you want to display as well. You can output it and start your loop at the second address instead.

Comment: Your solution is not optimal. You make the last iteration and tries to get next ip address which is never used.

Comment: Correct. He can move the First print out of the loop. I will make an edit.

Comment: How would it? By increasing the starting Index to +1 instand of 0, the number of iterations will be the same as yours, except that '" begin at 1" seems more understandable than "end one before the wanted amout"

Comment: You had corrected your answer right after my last comment, so I deleted it. In my example, I just tried to focus on the number of iteration, to make it clearer for the question author. Sure, 1 looks better)) so, +1 from me

Comment: Thanks man, +1 for sportsmanship, and because you were first to pull the first iteration out of the loop